# Google Maps Api JS- Список запрещенных зон и районов

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Добрый день!
Строю маршрут от одной точки к другой, используя Autocomplete. Как можно сделать так, чтоб если точка принадлежала указанному городу или адресу(прописывается в БД) то выводить сообщение, что данный город или район не поддерживает?
Например в списке Москва
Район можно получить, но если ввести не Москва, а например Moscow или Moskva, то фильтр уже не будет работать

```
     origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
        var vicinity = origin_autocomplete.getPlace().vicinity;
        if (!place.geometry) {
          window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
      origin_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
          directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });
```

Спасибо!

Comment: После геокодера сравнивать `formatted_address` с вашим городом не подходит?

Comment: Спасибо,
А если я введу например не Москва, а Moscow или Moskva.. В этом загвоздка

Comment: Для этого придется использовать алиасы. Если не найдено совпадение по имени, то переходить к алиасам.

Answer (score 1):

На запрещённые области можете создать полигоны и проверять, содержат ли эти полигоны вашу точку